# Port from winForms to Windows phone 8.0 C#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, xaml, windows-phone

can someone help me out by porting/translating this piece of c# code wrote in winForms to Windows phone 8.0 ? Im really struggling with it and i cant make it work i probably read every single documentation that i could get my hands on but i just cant make it work. I know that stackover flow is not place where people write code for you but im hopeless.. any help is appreciated Im trying to load some info about my app from a text document and image im loading those things in array of images and array of strings. Here's the code :

```
private static string[] _folderPaths = Directory.GetDirectories(@"Folders");
    private string[] _imagePaths;
    private List<string> _questionsPaths = new List<string>();
    private List<string> _correctAnswersPaths = new List<string>();
    private List<string> _allAnswersPaths = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < _folderPaths.Length; i++)
        {
            var _tempLocations = Directory.GetFiles(_folderPaths[i], (i + 1).ToString() + "*.txt*");
            _imagePaths = Directory.GetFiles(_folderPaths[i], "*.png", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            foreach (string item in _tempLocations)
            {
                if (item == "Folders\\" + (i + 1).ToString() + "\\" + (i + 1).ToString() + ".txt")
                {
                    _questionsPaths.Add(item);
                }
                if (item == "Folders\\" + (i + 1).ToString() + "\\" + (i + 1).ToString() + "answer" + ".txt")
                {
                    _correctAnswersPaths.Add(item);
                }
                if (item == "Folders\\" + (i + 1).ToString() + "\\" + (i + 1).ToString() + "answers" + ".txt")
                {
                    _allAnswersPaths.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: So what isn't working?  How is it not working?  Where is it going wrong?  All you said is "I can't make it work", that is very vague.  What do you mean by that?

Comment: I gave up on doing it for windows phone simply because i couldn't make this piece of winForms code into my windows phone app. I dont have any samples left to show im really sorry..

Answer (score 0):

The corresponding types used in Windows Phones are (not precise mapping, of course):

```
Directory -> StorageFolder
Directory.GetDirectories -> StorageFolder.GetFoldersAsync
Directory.GetFiles -> StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync
```

So the translated code would be something like this (you need to be familiar with the new `await-async` keywords too)

```
using Windows.Storage; 

var folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFolderAsync("Folders"); 
var subFolders = await folder.GetFoldersAsync();
foreach (StorageFolder subFolder in subFolders)
{
    var tempFiles = await subFolder.GetFilesAsync(...
```

Comment: They've now renamed directories to folders on the code level and not just on the UI level? Awwwww.

Comment: Where does ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder refers to ? Im getting FileNotFoundException

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen I use them interchangeably

Comment: That's my current location of my "Folders" folder Desktop\WPBluetoothDemo\WPBluetoothDemo\Bin\Debug how can i access it ?

Comment: Try `Package.Current.InstalledLocation`

Comment: `var folder = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Folders");` wont work